# ¿Hay alguna alternativa a "padre" o a "madre" que carezca de género?

Tags: vocabulario, neutralidad-de-género

Por supuesto, sé que por el momento, tanto el español formal como el coloquial emplean "los padres" para referirse a los progenitores de todo género, y que el lenguaje inclusivo "convencional" por así decirlo suele optar por decir ambas palabras de forma explícita: "los padres y las madres".

No obstante, obviamente hay gente que no se autoidentifica ni como masculina ni como femenina. Por ejemplo, hay personas que son agénero (que no tienen género) o de un tercer género, o cuya identidad de género engloba tanto algunos aspectos masculinos como otros femeninos. Y ese no es un listado completo.

Supongo que muchas personas que se autoindentifican así prefieren no llamarse "padre" o "madre", y usan otro término; además, de por sí a "las madres y los padres" le falta brevedad. Entonces, ¿hay alguna palabra que signifique lo mismo y que carezca de género en un sentido semántico<sup>1</sup> (si no gramatical)?

<sub>1: Como "una persona" o "un ser humano"</sub>

Comment: En el ámbito educativo se recomienda usar "las familias" en lugar de "los padres y las madres" (por lo menos en mi zona).

Comment: Creo que no hay que exagerar.

Comment: @Lambie - No creo haber exagerado en la pregunta. ¿A qué te refieres en particular?

Comment: Me refiero a que **depende del contexto**. Pero progenitor no funciona si las dos personas no quieren identificarse con uno sexo o otro. Progenitor implica relaciones sexuales. Hay que preguntar a las personas lo que ellos quieren decir.

Comment: "Hay que preguntar a las personas lo que ellos quieren decir." Bueno, de ahí la pregunta. Ojo, yo no he sido el que escribió que "progenitor" es la palabra correcta en este caso, sino que una respuesta lo sugirió como una posibilidad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quizás [progenitor](https://dle.rae.es/progenitor), que según el [Diccionario de la lengua española](https://dle.rae.es) de la Real Academia Española, es:

> 1. m. y f. Pariente en línea recta ascendente de una persona.

Comment: Pero entonces eso incluye a los abuelos?

Comment: Si bien es cierto que la entrada dice "m. y f. " (masculino y femenino) el uso correcto que se desprende de la entrada es "progenitor, ra" y cada uno de estos corresponde a esos "m. y f. " indicados en la acepción. En conclusión, no creo que este término valga mejor que "padre y madre", porque los individuos estarían sujetos a usar "progenitor o progenitora".

Comment: @wimi las otras dos acepciones indican "2. m. y f. Biol. Ser vivo que origina a otro." y "3. m. pl. El padre y la madre." por l oque entiendo que la primera acepción incluye a cualquier ancestro, mientras que la segunda y tercera solo al ancestro inmediatamente superior en la linea.

Comment: Un progenitor, por definición, tiene un sexo.

Comment: Pero si usamos la palabra "progenitores" ya no lleva género explícito. Además, aunque la acepción incluiría a los abuelos, bisabuelos, etc., el contexto los descartaría en la práctica.

Answer (score 3):

Depende de contexto. Progenitor está bien dicho pero es muy formal.

Reunión de padres, y va la madre, está bien dicho, y padres se refiere a padres y madres, en español recordemos que el masculino plural suele implicar al femenino también (digo, tengo muchos amigos, implica amigas también). Sin embargo, en el caso de una pareja en la que uno de los dos sea transexual, se diría reunión de padres, puesto que el colegio no entiende de género de la persona, se refiere tanto a uno como a otro, y llama la atención puesto que tradicionalmente, la mujer, la madre suele tener una mayor implicación en estos temas.

En otro ejemplo podría decir 'el niño carece de una buena figura parental', suena rimbombante, pero no está mal dicho, como sean los padres y su sexualidad.

La que más se aproxima es progenitor pero depende de ambientes y contexto.

Si tenemos en cuenta el sexo del progenitor, mujeres que se identifican como hombres o viceversa incluidos... el uso de uno u otro término depende del contexto, el tipo de texto, etc... pero no hay uno específico o más usado para este caso.

Comment: Lo de la figura parental suena a que funcionaría. Sin embargo, realmente me interesaría saber qué términos utilizan precisamente las personas a quienes he mencionado en la pregunta.

Comment: Como se puede decir genitor si no ha tenido el niño/niña??

Answer (score 2):

Creo que se puede usar la expresión **parental**:

> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a los padres o a los parientes.
> 2. adj. Biol. Que se refiere a uno o a ambos progenitores. U. t. c. s.

De hecho, en una consulta similar, la [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/paternidad-maternidad/) propone una palabra derivada: **parentalidad**.

> No obstante, el uso del sustantivo parentalidad es cada vez más frecuente, aunque no está recogido en los principales diccionarios, y sirve perfectamente para denominar la relación de los padres con el hijo.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un neologismo que a mí personalmente me encanta que es "adre". Se usa en entornos que hablan en género neutro terminando palabras con la "e". Ejemplo: "une adre que tiene dos hijes".

Comment: ¿De verdad? Nunca había visto esta palabra. ¿Puedes poner algún ejemplo real de publicación?

Answer (score 0):

#### Tutores

No significa lo mismo pero lleva lleva "e" y elimina connotaciones  biológicas. Solo evita decir tutor o tutora. Además es mas inclusiva porque engloba a aquellos que no tienen padres.

Aunque alguien podría replicar ¡Pero, también existe la palabra tutoras! Entonces diré ¡Me rindo!

Answer (score -1):

Esta es la publicación donde viene lo que dice Raq:
https://nobinario.tumblr.com/post/106660050242/madre-padre-neidre-adre-hadre-y
En resumen, hay distintas palabras que ha ideado la comunidad no binaria para dar respuesta a esa pregunta:

- Neidre, neinei, neini
- Adre, adá, adi
- Hadre, hadá, hadi
- Edre, edé, edi

También veo en otras respuestas que hay cierta confusión entre identidad sexual/de género y sexualidad (que se suele referir más bien a la atracción sexual). Además de que la transexualidad (binaria) tiene poco que ver con la pregunta.

Comment: Esas palabras no parecen tener un uso general, sino que solo las usan el escritor del blog y su "grupo de amigos"

Comment: ¿La "comunidad"? ¿qué comunidad? Buscas "neinei" y sale una funda para el Samsung Galaxy.